# Why is my rigidbody broken?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

[image]

Both rigid bodies have mesh collisions.
[image]

Comment: apply the scale? set the origin to geometry?

Comment: what does "apply the scale" mean?

Comment: Please add images showing your settings for the objects. There is not nearly enough information here to help you. Consider adding a [sample file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) as well. Are all object transforms applied? Are origins placed properly?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: the origins are fine, how do I apply transforms? I will add images showing settings..

Comment: ok, whenever I apply transformations, the origin goes back to its original spot.

Comment: @OliverYeet any additional information should be added into your question as an [edit]. This does not work as a forum (as a continual post). Comments are [temporary bits of information](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) that many users do not bother reading as they are often discarded.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of shape (the zero) using *convex hull* seems to work better than using mesh.

From the [manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties/collisions.html#collisions) on collisions:

> **Convex Hull**
>
> A mesh-like surface encompassing (e.g. shrink-wrapped over) all
> vertices (best results with fewer vertices). A convex approximation of
> the object, which has good performance and stability.

> **Mesh**
>
> Mesh consisting of triangles only, allowing for more detailed interactions than convex hulls. Allows simulating concave objects, but
> is rather slow and unstable.

In your case, using convex hull stabilizes things much more.

---

Here is the difference between mesh and convex hull in your case:

Mesh:

[image]
Convex Hull:
[image]